# Jenkins Slave build locations

Tags: jenkins

I have just added a slave to my Jenkins build - with the idea that I can now deploy artefacts to either my dev server or my test server.
However i've now hit a problem. 
When I deploy a job on the master slave, the job build directory is 
$JENKINS_HOME/localmoduledirectory  (as defined in the build job)
However when I deploy my job via the slave the build directory is different which breaks my jobs. The build directory is 
$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/build job title/localmoduledirectory

I know I can change the workspace root directory location for the master under configure settings /advances .. so can change it to $JENKINS_HOME/workspace, but I want to stop the slave using the build job title in the path. 
The end result I'm after is to have jenkins, building / deploying from the same location on two servers i.e /opt/jenkins/workspace/localmoduledirectory.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

ok after lots of head scratching ...
managed to discover that the mvn plugin has a custom workspace option hidden under advanced. so configured all jobs with a customer workspace of /opt/jenkins.